# Indication that SageMaker’s input_mode “FastFile” is active

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

When i use SM’s input_mode = “File” or input_mode = “Pipe”, I find reflection of that in input_data_config:

"input_data_config": {"train": {"TrainingInputMode": "File",
"S3DistributionType": "ShardedByS3Key",
"RecordWrapperType": "None"}

"input_data_config": {"train": {"TrainingInputMode": “Pipe”,
"S3DistributionType": "ShardedByS3Key",
"RecordWrapperType": "None"}

But when I specify “FastFile” it refers to the “File” in the input_data_config:

"input_data_config": {"train": {"TrainingInputMode": "File",
"S3DistributionType": "ShardedByS3Key",
"RecordWrapperType": "None"}

Does it mean that my implementation fails to use “FastFile” input_data_mode or there should be no "TrainingInputMode": “FastFile" entry in the “input_data_config” when that mode is used?

My Code is:

```
*****************************************************
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

hyperparameters = {"input_mode": "FastFile", #"FastFile", "Pipe", "File"
                  "shards_on_input": 4 # 4, 120 (for input subfolders in S3)
                  }

train_input = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput("s3://mnist-tdrecords/train/{}".format(hyperparameters["shards_on_input"]),  
                                             input_mode = hyperparameters["input_mode"],
                                             distribution = 'ShardedByS3Key' #'ShardedByS3Key', 'FullyReplicated'
                                            )

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point = "AWS_DataPipping_TFMirroredStrategy.py",
                          source_dir = "./",
                          framework_version = "2.3",
                          py_version = "py37",
                          instance_type = "ml.p3.2xlarge", # "ml.p3.2xlarge", "ml.p3.8xlarge", "ml.p3.16xlarge"
                          instance_count = 1,
                          role = sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
                          hyperparameters = hyperparameters,
                          output_path = f"s3://mnist-tdrecords/output",
                          input_mode = hyperparameters["input_mode"], # "File", "Pipe", "FastFile")
                         )

s3_data_channels = {"train": train_input}
#s3_data_channels = {"train": "s3://mnist-tdrecords/train/{}".format(hyperparameters["shards_on_input"])}
                    #"validation": f"s3://{bucket_name}/data/validation",}

tf_estimator.fit(s3_data_channels)

*****************************************************
```